# I am trying to convert a String date to long

Tags: java, android, string, date, long-integer

I am converting string date into `long`, but I don’t understand how to return the `long` value
and how to convert a string into long and store in room database

```
package com.example.mybugetssimple;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateConverter {

   public static long dateCon(String string_date){

        string_date = "12-December-2012";

           SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
           try {
               Date d = f.parse(string_date);
               long milliseconds = d.getTime();
               return milliseconds;
           } catch (ParseException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: Which is the lowest API level your app is supporting?

Comment: As the date is not supported in room database you need to use TypeConverter. Check out this link https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data#type-converters

Comment: does the return type is correct

Comment: Yes, the return type of ```Long``` is correct, you just have to use ```date.getTime()``` while storing it as ```Long``` and while retrieving you can use a new date object from the long value.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Your code works on my Java 9 and returns 1355288400000. It may be a locale problem. What us your default locale?

Comment: [I downvoted because “I don’t understand how to …” is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
   public static String getStringDateFormTimeStamp(long timestamp) {
    try {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, tz.getOffset(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date currenTimeZone = calendar.getTime();
        return sdf.format(currenTimeZone);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Timber.d(e);
    }
    return "";
}


 public static long StringDateToTimeStamp(String string_date){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date d = null;
    try {
        d = f.parse(string_date);
        calendar.setTime(d);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return calendar.getTimeInMillis();

}
```

Comment: change your DateFormat as per you requirement

Answer (score 1):

Use this way

```
  public static long dateCon(String string_date){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        Date d = null;
        try {
            d = f.parse(string_date);
            calendar.setTime(d);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    }
```

Comment: you also get string date as per your question and make method also pass string date.